# Manage Alert event at the start of application

Tags: ios, alert, ios-ui-automation

I'm working under test automation for some app and faced with issue that i cannot manage Alert at the start of app.
When my app starts i get alert - "Would Like to Use Your Current Location" with Don't Allow and OK buttons.
I tried the following code:

```
UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert){
    return false; // use default handler
}
```

Also i tried the following thing:

```
UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert) {
        alert.buttons()["OK"].tap();
        return true;
}
```

But it doesn't lead to expected result:
Could not start script, target application is not frontmost.

So, i need help. I see 2 solutions: first it's handle this alert in someway, maybe someone know how? second way, it's use some script and set permissions for my app in Simulator Settings but i also don't have any idea how i can realize that.

Thanks everybody who try to answer!!

This solution is great for me:

```
tell application "iPhone Simulator"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iPhone Simulator"
        click button "OK" of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Preconditions:
Turn On on your Mac:
System Preferences > Accessibility > Enable access for assistive devices

Thanks a lot [Shaun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/786845/shaun) for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This alert provide by system *(`Apple iOS`)* so, you are not able to handle it or can not do any changes with it so best way is stop fighting with it :)

Comment: hmm... but maybe there is some solution how to fix it?

Comment: Nothing to fix it :*(

Comment: maybe some apple script to a simulator?

Comment: Then try to search if anythings you get that solve your issue that also give me also need it :)